# How to add member to role without having to mention it? [Discord.JS]

Tags: discord.js

at the moment I am trying to make a role command for my bot. For example: `t!role add @person <name of role>`. But I can't figure out how to get the role as people have usernames with different lengths so I cannot use `.slice` which I have been able to use for creating a role

Currently my bot says that it can't find that role

My code:

```
const config = require("../../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "role",
    description: "Creates/removes roles from server and adds/removes roles from members",
    category: "utility",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        let messageRole = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length + 12).trim();
        const findRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === messageRole);

        if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use this command");

        if (args[0].toLowerCase() == "create") {
            let roleName = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length + 12);
            if (!roleName) return message.channel.send("You need to specify a name for the role");
            let newRole = await message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: roleName, permissions: false } });
            message.channel.send(`**${roleName}** has been created`);

        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "delete") {
            if (!findRole) return message.channel.send("You need to specify a role to be deleted\n\n" + messageRole);
            findRole.delete();
            message.channel.send(`${findRole.name} has been deleted`);

        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "add") {
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("You need to mention the member you want to give the role to");
            if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send("I can't find that member");
            if (!args[2]) return message.channel.send("You need to specify a role I have to give");
            if (!findRole) return message.channel.send("I can't find that role");

            if (mentionedMember.roles.cache.has(findRole)) return message.channel.send(`${mentionedMember.name} already has that role`);
            mentionedMember.addRole(findRole);
            message.channel.send(`${mentionedMember.name} has been given the role ${findRole.name}`)
            return undefined

        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "remove") {
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("You need to mention the member you want to remove the role from");
            if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send("I can't find that member");
            if (!args[2]) return message.channel.send("You need to specify a role I have to remove");
            if (!mentionedRole) return message.channel.send("I can't find that role");

            if (!mentionedMember.roles.cache.has(mentionedRole.id)) return message.channel.send(`${mentionedMember} doesnt have that role`);
            mentionedMember.roles.remove(mentionedRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`**${mentionedRole.name}** has been removed from ${mentionedMember}`);
            return undefined
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `message.mentions.roles` instead?

Answer (score -1):

Slice the amount of `args`. If you slice an array, it will remove one entire value from it.

```js
[1, 2, 3].slice(2)
// result: [3]
```

Since `args` is an array, all you have to do is `args.slice(2)`, assuming `args` does not include the command message.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response!
I have tried that but when I try ```args.slice(2)``` or for that matter any number the bot replies with: "add @Dennis a" isnt a role
although args.shift does seem to help I haven't yet found out how to shift 2 arguments